# why i can't import the following dataset from uci

Tags: r, data-import

Good afternoon ,

Assume we have the following function :

```
data_preprocessing<-function(link,drop_last_column=TRUE){
  
  link=as.character(link) 
  DT <- data.table::fread(link, 
                          fill = TRUE,
                          na.strings = "?") 
  DT=DT[-1,]
  DT=as.data.frame(DT)
  
  if(drop_last_column==TRUE){
    DT=as.data.frame(DT)[,-ncol(DT)]
  }
  
  
  return(DT)
  
}
```

When i try to import `acute` dataset from `uci` , i get the following error :

```
acute=data_preprocessing("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/acute/diagnosis.data")
 [100%] Downloaded 7276 bytes...
Error in data.table::fread(link, fill = TRUE, na.strings = "?") : 
  File is encoded in UTF-16, this encoding is not supported by fread(). Please recode the file to UTF-8.
```

I also tried :

```
acute=read.csv("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/acute/diagnosis.data")
Warning messages:
1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 2 appears to contain embedded nulls
3: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 3 appears to contain embedded nulls
4: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 4 appears to contain embedded nulls
5: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 5 appears to contain embedded nulls
6: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  embedded nul(s) found in input
```

Thank you for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use read.table with appropriate encoding instead.

```
data_preprocessing<-function(link,drop_last_column=TRUE){
  
  link=as.character(link) 
  DT <- read.table(link, 
                   fileEncoding="UTF-16", 
                   fill = TRUE, 
                   na.strings = "?") 
  DT=DT[-1,]
  DT=as.data.frame(DT)
  
  if(drop_last_column==TRUE){
    DT=as.data.frame(DT)[,-ncol(DT)]
  }
  
  
  return(DT)
  
}

acute=data_preprocessing("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/acute/diagnosis.data")

head(acute)
    V1 V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7
2 35,9 no  no yes yes yes yes
3 35,9 no yes  no  no  no  no
4 36,0 no  no yes yes yes yes
5 36,0 no yes  no  no  no  no
6 36,0 no yes  no  no  no  no
7 36,2 no  no yes yes yes yes
```

**Edit:**
To find automatically the encoding used in the data file, you can use the guess_encoding function in readr package.

```
data_preprocessing<-function(link,drop_last_column=TRUE){
  
  link=as.character(link) 
  enc_guess <- readr::guess_encoding(link)
  enc <- enc_guess[enc_guess$confidence == max(enc_guess$confidence),]$encoding
  DT <- read.table(link, 
                   fileEncoding = enc, 
                   fill = TRUE, 
                   na.strings = "?") 
  DT=DT[-1,]
  DT=as.data.frame(DT)
  
  if(drop_last_column==TRUE){
    DT=as.data.frame(DT)[,-ncol(DT)]
  }
  
  
  return(DT)
  
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! but how can i know the used encoding of the file in the general case : For this situation i solved the pb by using notepad++ . After that i copied the data into excel then i saved the file as .csv

Comment: After that i used read.csv("C:/Users/user/Desktop/diagnosis.csv")

Comment: There is function in readr package. Check the edited answer.

Comment: Thank you again sir for your precious help !